# Scrapy spider behaving differently on different environments

Tags: scrapy

I have written a Scrapy spider for scraping, but am facing an issue.

If I run the spider from my local machine it runs perfectly but when I deploy it on DigitalOcean droplet and run it from there I get a response of [444 "CONNECTION CLOSED WITHOUT RESPONSE"](https://httpstatuses.com/444) from the target site.

I have tried changing the droplet in case the droplet's IP has been blocked (the spider has completed 4, 5 runs before) but the issue remains.

What I am looking for is some way to debug the issue.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to make the spider use the same IP locally and remotely, through a proxy. Once you do that, you can determine if the issue is related to the IP address (likely) or not.

Comment: it turned out that the target website is behaving differently for different regions.